# Decomposition of expressions (operations on Matrix), hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, matrix, scalding

I'm trying to make a sort of mini framework for big matrix calculations on hadoop; what i mean, smth like~ `Prod(Sum(x, y), z) // (X + Y) * Z` , where x, y, z - matrix or numbers, and calculate it, and write some output result into file.
So I'm using `Scalding`, matrix and number is in fact the same thing. 
And the problem, that I dont know how to deal with decomposition.

Let me explain what I mean: if we r talking about numbers (now without `hadoop`, `scalding`, etc, only pure `Scala`) we can make in a such way:

```
trait Expr {
    def eval: Int = this match {
    case Number(n) => n
    case Sum(e1, e2) => e1.eval + e2.eval
    case Diff(e1, e2) => e1.eval - e2.eval
    case Prod(e1, e2) => e1.eval * e2.eval
}
```

So u see my idea. But with hadoop, as I recognize correct, we should make `Jobs` and send em on `hadoop`;
So the only way I see, is to deal with file names of matrix. But there at least four problems:

1. How to make a right decomp trait (like this `Expr`, case as i see, we can deal only with `Strings` - names of files)?
2. How to run jobs from inside of any class, wich is not a job? so i mean a class where I could pass matrix names, and it will send everyting and calculate on hadoop, and then bring result back? and i see that it would be better to send on hadoop only input files, and send back only result output. (So chains of some operations? but how to make them, the way I see is to send a Job which make decomposition and calculates everything? But how to make this big job, if the Job depends on `Expression` to evaluate. Another variant - to send each Job (`Sum`, `Prod`, etc) separately.)
3. How can I operate with output files? If we got lots of operations, all results for middle calculations we chould store, and how to keep file names?
4. Are my thoughts right?

P.S. thank u, it will be very helpful to show me some examples of similar ideas (links), to understand hadoop more, cause I didn't find lots of information about it. And the most problematic question, is how to run Jobs from any class.

---

**Solved**

So I found a way, I got one job of decompostion, it was not too clever question 'cause I didn't understand the process I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Scalding already has a Matrix API ( https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Introduction-to-Matrix-Library ). You could check how it's implemented there.

Btw, for smaller matrices we use breeze:
https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/UserGuide

Comment: thx for response, but the question was in organizing Jobs to make a decomposition of some expression wich conists of couple of eoperations and solving em on haddop, using scalding. The question is solved - I found way to organize and run my Jobs :) thx.